# Diferencias entre substr(), substring() y slice() Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, substring, substr

Estaba haciendo esta función para formatear un numero poniendo `','` cada 3 dígitos, primero intente con `substring()` no me funcionaba,  estaba seguro que la lógica era buena y que estaba recordando algo mal así que intente con `substr()` y funciono.

Luego revise la documentación y leí algo como que el `substr()` estaba en camino a ser deprecado.

Si fuera así para este mismo caso con el `substring()` y el `slice()` seria mas enredado. la diferencia que encontré son los parámetros que se le pasan, pero igual son muy similares; no se si en el interior funcionan diferente.

```js
function groupByCommas3(n) {
    let s = reverse(`${n}`)
    arr = [];
    for (let i = 0, l = s.length; i < l; i += 3) {
        arr.push(s.substr(i, 3))
    }
    return reverse(arr.join(','))
}
function reverse(cadena) {
    return cadena.split('').reverse().join('')
}

console.log(groupByCommas3(35235235));
console.log(groupByCommas3(1000000));
```

Comment: [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/substr) esta obsoleto, prefiere usar subsring y el slice, es para cortar; por ultimo si quieres dar formato numerico te recomiendo [NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)

Comment: Aquí puedes ver las diferencias: http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/substring-substr-slice-javascript/

Comment: @xero399 por lo que he visto no existe tal pregunta en SOes, o yo no la he encontrado, por lo que te animo a responderla (si quieres) y así ganar unos puntos

Comment: La función number_format() hace lo que buscas automáticamente....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Resumiendo las diferencias:**

`String.prototype.substr()` no está estrictamente obsoleto, pero no se recomienda su uso ya que puede dar resultados inconsistentes.

`String.prototype.substring()` devuelve un subconjunto de un objeto String.

`String.prototype.slice()` extrae una sección de una cadena y devuelve una cadena nueva.

`slice()` funciona como `substring()`con algunos comportamientos diferentes.

```
Syntaxis: string.slice(inicio, fin);
Syntaxis: string.substring(inicio, fin);
```

**Lo que tienen en común:**

- Si `inicio` es igual `fin`: devuelve una cadena vacía.
- Si `fin` se omite: extrae caracteres hasta el final de la cadena.
- Si cualquiera de los argumentos es mayor que la longitud de la cadena, se utilizará
  en su lugar la longitud de la cadena.

**Distinciones de :substring()**

- Si `inicio` > `fin`, entonces `substring` intercambiará esos 2
  argumentos.
- Si cualquiera de los argumentos es negativo o lo es    `NaN`, se
  trata como si lo fuera `0`.

**Distinciones de :slice()**

- Si `inicio` > `fin`, `slice()` devolverá la cadena vacía. (`""`).
- Si `inicio` es negativo: se establece el resultado desde el final de
  la cadena, exactamente como `substr()` en Firefox. Este
  comportamiento se observa tanto en Firefox como en IE.
- Si `inicio` es negativo: se establece `fin` en: `string.length –
  Math.abs(fin)`(valor original), excepto limitado a 0 (por lo tanto
  `Math.max(0, string.length + fin)`) como se cubre en la
  especificación ECMA .

Fuente: [Rudimentary Art of Programming & Development: Javascript: substr() v.s. substring()](https://rapd.wordpress.com/2007/07/12/javascript-substr-vs-substring/)

---

Luego para el problema que estas resolviendo (agrupar por comas de 3 en 3), creo que la función `match` es mas adecuada para el trabajo:

`String.prototype.match()` se usa para obtener todas las ocurrencias de una expresión regular dentro de una cadena.

En el siguiente código se ve como funciona:

```js
function groupByCommas3(n) {
    let s = reverse(`${n}`).match(/.{1,3}/g);
    return reverse(s.join(','))
}
function reverse(cadena) {
    return cadena.split('').reverse().join('')
}

console.log(groupByCommas3(35235235));
console.log(groupByCommas3(1000000));
```

esa es toda la información que te puedo dar sobre extracción de cadenas, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias the-breaker muy completa la respuesta :) saludos!

Comment: @IsraelGonzález de nada.